# Importing a Swing object into Matlab

Tags: java, matlab

I'm trying to import [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2007/jw-09-checkboxtree.html?page=2) into a Matlab project. I'm aware that I would need to refer to `com.mathworks.mwswing.checkboxtree` and `com.mathworks.mwswing.MJTree` libraries on Matlab already. I've pretty much gone through the docs related to importing Java into Matlab [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f44062.html), including the sub-sections.

However, I still have no idea how I would accomplish what I'm trying to do in Matlab, and having trouble finding examples. How can I find out how to include those specific objects?

Btw, here's what I got by typing `javaclasspath` command:

```
>> javaclasspath

        STATIC JAVA PATH

    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\java\patch                                                       
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\java\jarext\AnimatedTransitions.jar                              
    ...                                             
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\java\jar\mwswing.jar                                             
    ...

        DYNAMIC JAVA PATH

        <empty>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Undocumented Secrets of Matlab-Java Programming](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/matlab-java-book/).

Also, [undocumentedmatlab.com](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/) is a great resources provided by the author of the before mentioned book, as @High Performance Mark remarks.

Comment: Whether OP minds or not, the author's website is indispensable.